# Text Attributes (via NSAttributedString) not applied to UITextFields

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextfield

I have some default styles to apply to a couple of UITextFields. I have the default styles on `AppModel.swift` as follows:

```swift
static let memeTextDefaultAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
    .strokeColor: UIColor.black,
    .font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 32)!,
    .strokeWidth: 2
  ]
```

Then, on the below function I set the default styles to the corresponding UITextFields, however, when running the app, no styles are actually applied.

```swift
/// Sets up the meme's top and bottom text fields' initial configuration
  func setInitialMemeTextConfig() {
    let memeTextFields = [memeTopText!, memeBottomText!]
    
    for (index, memeTextField) in memeTextFields.enumerated() {
      memeTextField.defaultTextAttributes = AppModel.memeTextDefaultAttributes
      memeTextField.textAlignment = AppModel.memeTextAlignment
      
      if index == 0 {
        memeTextField.text = AppModel.topMemeTextFieldDefaultText
        memeTextField.delegate = memeTopTextFieldDelegate
      } else {
        memeTextField.text = AppModel.bottomMemeTextFieldDefaultText
        memeTextField.delegate = memeBottomTextFieldDelegate
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm relatively new to iOS programming so if this is a silly mistake of me, please excuse me.

Comment: You can create an attributed string (NSAttributedString) with the attributes you created then assign it to the yourTextField.attributedText (not .text).

Comment: Thanks, @koen. Yes, that post answered my question, so mine is pretty much a duplicate.